# Find the expression of a function close to this drawing

Tags: graphing-functions, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to model mechanical response under constraint in materials, and I know that I need this kind of function if I want my model to be accurate. [image]

The point is, I have absolutely no idea about how to build such function (equal to 0 if x>R), and I don't really want to use B-splines or I don't know what interpolation or something.
I already tried this function : $$\frac{e^{\frac{-x}{2}}\times sin(2\pi x/R)\times (R-x)}{x^2}$$ but it just doesn't work. I know that I can put E in my sin, but then it causes another problem...

So, if anybody has an idea, even something that isn't exactly looking like this plot, or if you know some encyclopedia where I can find a typical function data-base or something, feel free to help me :)

Comment: $y=-(\ln x/x)+1/(2e)$ is close, but it may not be what you want. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-logx%2Fx%2B1%2F%282e%29

Comment: It is definitly superclose, but i need something with a 0-derivative in R :/